# How to replace carriage return \n with a space

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

So in jasper I have a field that has a variable in it to format the string but in the webapp where I am getting the data from it will print the carriage return such as "line1\nline2\nline3\nline4" How would I fix this?

```
SELECT
  CAST(modulesettings.value::json->'soReportFooter' AS varchar) AS footer_value
FROM modulesetting
WHERE modulesetting.key = 'sales'
```

Then the variable expression to take the quotes of the end is
$F{footer_value}.substring(1, $F{footer_value}.length() -1)

Comment: `'\n'` is not "carriage return", it's "line feed". "Carriage return" is `'\r'`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-EscapeSequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [a string function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT
  replace(CAST(modulesettings.value::json->'soReportFooter' AS varchar, '\n', ' ') AS footer_value
FROM modulesetting
WHERE modulesetting.key = 'sales'
```

Comment: '\n' is not interpreted as a new line by PG, it is the string composed of a backslash and a N. Plus, parenthesis are not even balanced.